# Using 7-zip cmd line from Python with subprocess

Tags: python, cmd, zip, subprocess, 7zip

I am trying to run 7zip through a command line code from a Python script using subprocess library.

The code below works fine when I use it directly in the command line. However, I am not capable to make it run with subprocess.

```
set path="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\";%path%
7z x C:\\Users\\ferro\\Desktop\\teste.zip -pabc123 -oC:\\Users\\ferro\\Desktop -aos -y
```

The current code I am trying to execute is the following.

```
    import subprocess
    import os

    os.system('set path="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\";%path%')
    command01 = ['7z', 'x', 'C:\\Users\\ferro\\Desktop\\teste.zip', '-p', 'abc123', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\ferro\\Desktop', '-aos', '-y']

    subprocess.call(command01)
```

The error message is "***FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]***"

Does anyone know where is my mistake?

Comment: You have to be careful with backslashes in strings. That can indicate a control character in some cases. Would you please try doing the following?: `os.system(r'set path="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\";%path%')`

Comment: Hi, bernie. Thank you for the explanation. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately I had the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Your environment settings (including the PATH variable) will not be passed to the subprocess. You could copy, edit and pass them like this:

```
myenv = os.environ.copy()
myenv['PATH'] = '<path>;' + myenv['PATH']
subprocess.call(..., env=myenv)
```

But why don't you just call 7-zip with it's full path instead of fiddling with the PATH variable?

```
command01 = [r'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe', ...]
subprocess.call(command01)
```

BTW, you can also provide the full command as a single string (on Windows, conversion to string is [done anyway](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#converting-argument-sequence) under the hood):

```
command02 = r'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe ...'
subprocess.call(command02)
```

Comment: Does `subprocess` need the executable extension specified? `'C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe'`

Comment: @lit No, it doesn't require the extension. But it doesn't do harm either and might make things a bit clearer, so I will add it.

Comment: Thank you, amain. I used complete PATH directly in the code and I also fixed some syntax mistakes in the subprocess command and it's working now. For record, the error I had made was to split `-p` from the password and `-o` from the output directory. The final code is `command01 = ['C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z', 'x', 'C:\\Users\\ferro\\Desktop\\teste.zip', '-pabc123', '-oC:\\Users\\ferro\\Desktop\\', '-aoa', '-y']`